# Configure htaccess to ignore webroot subfolder, but to serve files contained within that subfolder, webroot contains a URL aliased webapp

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a Drupal website that has a page at the URL alias of `/news` however the client also needs to store files within the physical `/news/` folder for legacy purposes (files linked from old newsletters etc).

Going to `site.com/news` serves a 403 Forbidden however as the physical folder is taking precedence over the CMS, surely as defined within the Drupal 6 standard htaccess.

Is it possible to configure a separate htaccess file that resides within `/news/` perhaps, so I don't need to fiddle with the Drupal standard htaccess in case of software updates in the future possible cause the changes to be overwritten. This is quite unlikely however, as it's a Drupal 6 site which is about as mature as this major version is ever going to get, so modifying the webroot htaccess is not unreasonable either.

EDIT:

**Current .htaccess contents**

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id: .htaccess,v 1.90.2.5 2010/02/02 07:25:22 dries Exp $
```

Comment: Please add the current htaccess contents to your post.

Comment: Can you not just change the name used for your news module to newsitems or something similar?

Comment: It wasn't a news module, it was a View with the path `/news` and the client was adamant it must stay as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `/news/` folder I created a new `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php?q=news [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT:**

Added the second RewriteCond which was not needed in my staging environment, but seemingly is needed in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume your .htaccess is doing the standard check that web application do which is, if URI isn't a file or a directory redirect to the front controller, something along the lines of...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRules .* index.php
```

Since in your case `/news` is a directory, the second RewriteCond isn't being met, therefore it simply attempts to access the folder and gets a permissions error. The simplest solution would probably be to add in an exception for that file. The exact requirements would depend on what your current .htaccess file looks like, but putting something like the following at the top may do the job.

```
RewriteRule ^/news$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately didn't work :(. I've updated my question with further findings

Comment: Actually figured out the answer as I was updating my question!